# How to keep the files received from the server before you write to the database?

Tags: java, json, database

I need to keep files in queue or something like that ,
E.g when database server is down , then i need to keep this files as long as server is starting, so i am asking you .
What is the best way to do that ( i can recived ~ 1k files per sec ) .